# Facebook SDK Integration - Returns

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-4.0

I can't finish FB SDK integration in to my project, because I can't add these lines of code from their Quick Start Guide:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

because I already have a `return` there:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self LoginToGameCenter_iOS_7_forth_way];
    return YES;
}
```

As I know there couldn't be 2 `returns`. What should I do? How can I setup FB SDK then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self LoginToGameCenter_iOS_7_forth_way];
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Because you pass your application down into the FB SDK which has it's own `-didFinishLaunchignWithOptions` method-- which returns the `BOOL` that bubbles back up to your main app delegate, which in turn returns that `BOOL` again